# How can I get a list of licenses from intalled RPMs?

Tags: linux, open-source, licensing, fedora, rpm

We've been asked to list all the software and licenses used in our organization. Without deciding the value of this request, I'd like to get my Fedora laptop to answer the question easily.

```
rpm -qa
```

Gives me a list of packages, but no license data. My next step is to take that output and write a script to query each package's license.

Anyone got an easier idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{name}: %{license}\n"
```

Comment: I used this to count installed packages and licenses: `$ rpm -qa --qf "%{license}\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > ~/license_counts`. More info [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-rpm-command-to-count-the-numbers-of-license-791962/#post6265960). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm just bad at driving rpm.

```
rpm -qai
```

Output is a little untidy, but not too bad.

[Edit] Tidier output

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}: %{LICENSE}\n"
```